# Правильный вывод статьи под категорию?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, девелоперы!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Сейчас выводится таким образом (1 - категория, 2 - статья)

1)Природа
2)В мире животных

1)Природа
2) Растения

А нужно чтоб выводилось вот так:

1)Природа
2)В мире животных
2)растения

Имею MySQL базу с такими данными

2 таблицы: таблица caregories(имеет столбцы: id, title), таблица goods (имеет столбцы: id, name, category)

Вот таким кодом я вывожу

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'olegmowk_1', '1425pmrmsw', 'olegmowk_1');
if ($connect == false) {
    echo "Error connect";
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "
    SELECT categories.title, goods.name
    FROM categories
    INNER JOIN goods
    ON categories.id = goods.category
    ORDER BY categories.id;
");

while ( ($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ) {
    echo $cat['title'];
    echo " = ";
    echo $cat['name']; 
}
 
?>
```

Надеюсь все понятно объяснил

Comment: Вообще не понятно ничего, напишите на нормальном языке, мы не гугл :)

Comment: @ilyaplot исправил

Comment: @DmitriySimushev исправил

Comment: У вас есть title (Природа ), name(В мире животных, Растения).И вам надо вывести title, а затем имена, так?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю примерно так

```
while ( ($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ) {
$categoryarticles[$cat['title']][]=$cat['name']; //Статья помещается в массив, первый уровень которого это название категории, т.е. $categoryarticles['Природа'][0]='В мире животных'
}
```

Затем прокручиваем двумерный массив через foreach

```
foreach ($categoryarticles as $key=>$category) {
    echo $key;
    foreach ($category as $article) {
    echo $article;
    }
}
```

Пробелы только поставьте где надо.

Comment: Работает, спасибо огромное :)

Comment: Вот только как оформление добавить для name и title ?

Comment: А в каком формате вывод нужен ?

Comment: Ну к примеру чтоб на title сменить цвет, а на name сделать отступ вниз

Comment: можно реализовать?

Comment: Конечно можно,   echo '<span style="color:#222222"'.$key.'</span>'; а перенос вниз перед последней скобкой echo '<br />';